# Send email to the user

Tags: ionic4

I need, when the user click one button, that send email with more information from the report

Im tried to use emailComposer but i dont want it.

```
let email = {
       to: 'max@mustermann.de',
       cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
       bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
       attachments: [
         'file://img/logo.png',
         'res://icon.png',
         'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
         'file://README.pdf'
       ],
       subject: 'Cordova Icons',
       body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
       isHtml: true
     }

     // Send a text message using default options
     this.emailComposer.open(email);
```

That plugin open the email app, i just want to send email automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Please could you make your title more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just send an email using the device's users email account.

If you want to do this then you must use a third-party email sending service that has an API.

MailGun is pretty good and gives 10,000 free emails a month and then only 5USD for the next 10k.

There are a lot of different services out there though, just search for "transactional email provider" and you will find these types of companies.